# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap dropdown does not show up

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

When I am working with MVC my links does not appear. Code works well in CSS/HTML editor but the dropdown does not work while I test it on MVC layout.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color: #333;text-align: center;">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Books
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("New", "MyTemplate")">New books</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Recommend", "MyTemplate")">Recommended books</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Available", "MyTemplate")">Available books</a>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Categories
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Genres", "MyTemplate")">Genres</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Formats", "MyTemplate")">Formats</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("About", "MyTemplate")">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Contact", "MyTemplate")">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Please note that all links work properly except one's in dropdown(New, Recommend, Available, Genres, Formats).

Head contains scripts and bootstrap/css style files:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1" shrink-to-fit="no" />

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @RenderSection("head", false)
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/style.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
```

@Edit
Solution:
I had to download bootstrap 4.5. I have used 4.5 to style it but MVC had older version and this made problems. Solution is to download all scripts needed by bootstrap 4.5 and attaching CDN of bootstrap 4.5 :)

Comment: why do you have the same id on the second dropdown toggle as the first one ?

Comment: Good point. I already changed it in my app. Still it does not work

Comment: did you check the browser console for errors ?

Comment: Yes, no errors occur. When I start app and inspect element on browser it says that dropdown shows so I assume it is some issue with JS or JQuery

Comment: include the `jquery` and `bootstrap.js` in the end of the body tag in that order and try again

Comment: I have done it previously, did not helped

Comment: i just tried your example in a mvc environment and in a html editor and it worked in both see example: [dot net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3jKuk), and write your anchor tags using the `asp-action` and `asp-controller` tag helpers, and check if you have the lastest version of bootstrap because jquery 3.5.1 had breaking changes

Comment: I have encountered the problem. I had to download bootstrap 4.5. I have used 4.5 to style it but MVC had older version and this made problems. Solution is to download all scripts needed by bootstrap 4.5 and attaching CDN of bootstrap 4.5 :). Thank you everyone for help!